# Find the shortest distance between the curve $y^2=x$ to the line $y=x+1$

Tags: calculus, optimization, computational-geometry

> Find the shortest distance between the curve $y^2=x$
>   to the line $y=x+1$.

Im not sure how to attack a problem like this.

Comment: The solution to this exact problem is [here](http://www.askiitians.com/forums/Analytical-Geometry/24/56410/shortest-distance.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(t^2,t)$ be a point on $y^2=x$. Its distance to the line $x-y+1=0$ is

$$\left|\frac{t^2-t+1}{\sqrt{(1)^2+(-1)^2}}\right|=\frac{(t-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

So the shortest distance is $\frac{3}{4\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: If it was $y=x^2$, then $(t,t^2)$?
But how did you get $t^2-t+1$?

Comment: @oledole, distance of point $(x_0,y_0)$ from line $Ax+By+C=0$ is $$d=\frac{|Ax_0+By_0+C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$ Also, your curve is $y^2=x$, hence a point on it is of the form $(t^2,t)$.

Comment: Then it makes sense, thanks

Comment: Has another task there, almost the same just that:
$y=x^2$ and the line is $x-y+1$.
Now the point on $y=x^2$, will be $(t,t^2)$?

Comment: CY aries why is it so that you dropped normal from parabola to the line but not from line to the parabola

Answer (score 1):

Let the **parabola** and the **line** be parameterized as follows

$$\mathcal P := \{ (t_1^2, t_1) \mid t_1 \in \mathbb R \} \qquad \qquad \qquad \mathcal L := \{ (t_2, t_2+1) \mid t_2 \in \mathbb R \}$$

The *squared* distance between $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal L$ is given by the minimum of the *quartic* objective function

$$f (t_1, t_2) := \left( t_1^2 - t_2 \right)^2 + \left( t_1 - t_2 - 1 \right)^2$$

Differentiating $f$ with respect to $t_1$ and $t_2$ and finding where the partial derivatives vanish, we obtain a system of two polynomial equations

$$\begin{array}{rl} 4 t_{1} \left( t_{1}^{2} - t_{2} \right) + 2 t_{1} - 2 t_{2} - 2 &= 0\\ - 2 t_{1}^{2} - 2 t_{1} + 4 t_{2} + 2 &= 0\end{array}$$

whose solution is

$$(t_1, t_2) = \left( \frac 12, -\frac 18 \right)$$

Thus, the distance between the parabola and the line is

$$\sqrt{\left( \left( \frac 12 \right)^2 + \frac 18  \right)^2 + \left( \frac 12 + \frac 18 - 1 \right)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{9}{32}} = \color{blue}{\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{2}}}$$

---

#### Plot

[image]

---

#### SymPy code

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t1, t2 = symbols('t1 t2')
>>> squareddistance = (t1**2 - t2)**2 + (t1 - t2 - 1)**2
>>> solve([diff(squareddistance, t1), diff(squareddistance, t2)], t1, t2)
[(1/2, -1/8), (1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2, -1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2), (1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2, -1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)]
```

Thus, the unique real solution is `(1/2, -1/8)`.

Answer (score 0):

With Lagrange multipliers: you want minimize
$$(x-u)^2 + (y-v)^2$$
with the restrictions
$$y^2 - x = 0,\qquad u - v + 1 = 0.$$
The Lagrange system is the two previous equations plus:
$$2(x - u) = -\lambda,$$
$$2(y - v) = 2\mu y,$$
$$-2(x - u) = \mu,$$
$$-2(y - v) = \mu.$$
This is an homogeneous system and we want a solution $\ne(0,0,0,0)$ (why?), so the matrix of the system must be zero...

Comment: We havent learn lagrange yet. I think its the next course, but:
Has another task there, almost the same just that: y=x^2 and the line is x−y+1=0. Now the point on y=x^2, will be (t,t^2)?

Comment: Shouldn't the Lagrange system have 6 equations?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, yes. Edited.

Comment: @oledole, yes. $y = x ^2\iff (x,y) = (t,t^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate $y^2=x$.

Get the slope of the normal as $m=-2y$.

Also for the line $m=-1$. Equate them, which gives:

$y=1/2$

$x=1/4$

$D=\frac{1/4+1-1/2}{\sqrt2}$

$D=\frac3{4\sqrt 2}$