# Doubt regarding distance between parabola and a line(coordinate geometry)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

Here is a neat [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2274584/849036) by CY aries.

Here he has dropped a normal from parabola to line but I am unable to understand why not from line to parabola.

Original OP is inactive. So please do not close this question

Comment: Because finding the perpendicular from a point to a parabola is more complicated,

Comment: What precisely is the Question asking?  In fact the "dropped" segment is normal both to the parabola and to the line.  One might well have proceeded to first deduce the slope of the "dropped" segment from its incidence with the line (wherever that might occur), and then to work out where it meets the parabola perpendicularly.  Your saying the answer "by CY aries" is neat suggests you've read and understood it, which leaves open what extra explanation you may want.

Comment: @hardmath. I feel that the point would be different if the case was vice versa and i am not able to find a general proof for it

Comment: well i got it. Let us assume a point and the sum of perpendiculars from it to the curves. So the minima is when the point lies on curve and the distance between the line and parabola(point) is minimum

Comment: it could be either case even the point could lie on line but stackexchangers are smart :). Thanks everyone

Comment: Your Comments have helped me to surmise what was troubling you about the earlier Q&A.  It is a special case, in which we can exactly find the points of closest approach between two figures, a line on one hand and a parabola on the other.  In many cases finding the pair of points where two figures are closest needs more stepwise approximations.  So your intuition, that the order in which you would pick a point on one figure and then the other, can give different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to calculate the distance of given point from given line and that point can be in parametric form, but for calculating it other way around, you need to take point (t, t+1) on the line, draw a perpendicular to the line which passes through point (t, t+1) which would be x+y=2t+1, as you can see this will involve multiple lines depending on value of t and this has to satisfy the point on x=$y^2$ Which would make equation as $y^2 +y = 2t+1$ Solve for values of y and then you would have to calculate distance for each of them, which is nothing but simply complicating a very simple problem.